# Node module cross build targets for deployment in npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, node-modules

I have my ES6 module that I want to build to target different environments. I don't know how to do this or if I should use webpack or rollup.

#### Build targets

1. ES6 environments like Vue.
2. Commonjs like node backend or some webpack builds.
3. The browser, the script tag.

#### Project directory structure

---

src

--Dog.js

index.js

package.json

---

#### Project Files

Dog.js

```
class Dog{
  //Typical Dog stuff
}
export default Dog;
```

index.js

```
import Dog from "./src/Dog";
export {
  Dog
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  target: 'node',
  mode: 'production',
};
```

package.json (relevant parts)

```
"files": [
  "dist",
  "src"
]
```

Is there any way to automatize this process or should I just write a new library for each target manually? And if there is how the projects that import my module know which build is right for their environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i think it works with a minimal webpack configuration. The dist folder and its contents are created by webpack.

#### Project directory structure

---

src

--Dog.js

dist

--dog.common.js

--dog.lib.min.js

index.js

package.json

webpack.config.js

---

#### webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");

var commonJsConfig = {
  target: 'node',
  mode: 'production',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'dog.common.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs'
  }
};

var browserConfig = {
  target: 'web',
  mode: 'production',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'dog.lib.min.js'
  }
};

module.exports = [commonJsConfig, browserConfig];
```

#### package.json (relevant parts)

- main tells backend and webpack legacy projects to use the commonjs format.
- module is for es6 format
- unpkg for the browser
- files tell npm wich files to upload

```
"main": "dist/dog.common.js",
"module": "index.js",
"unpkg": "dist/dog.lib.min.js",
"files": [
  "dist",
  "src"
],
"scripts": {
  "build": "webpack"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use different webpack configs for different environments and targets. It is a common approach.

Comment: If i knew how to do that i would have done it not asked it. And  how the projects that import mine module know wich build is right for their environment? I have seen this done with the main: "..." of the package.json but what about the other environments